# Unable to export multiple cloud functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using the organization structure described [here](https://codeburst.io/organizing-your-firebase-cloud-functions-67dc17b3b0da). I have the following `functions/` folder:

[image]

My `index.js` file is as follows:

```
const glob = require('glob')
const camelCase = require('camelcase')
const FUNCTIONS_FOLDER = './src'

const files = glob.sync('./src/**/*.func.js', {
    cwd: __dirname,
    ignore: './node_modules/**'
})

console.log('FILE LENGTH: ', files.length)

for (let f = 0, fl = files.length; f < fl; f++) {
    const file = files[f]
    console.log('FILE: ', file)

    const functionName = camelCase(
        file
            .slice(5, -8)
            .split('/')
            .join('_')
    ) // Strip off '.func.js' and 'src/'
    console.log('FUNCTION - PRE: ', functionName)
    console.log('ENV ', process.env.FUNCTION_NAME)
    if (
        !process.env.FUNCTION_NAME ||
        process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === functionName
    ) {
        console.log('FUNCTION: ', functionName, file)
        exports[functionName] = require(file)
    }
}
```

and I am trying to deploy the two cloud functions defined in the `functions/src/votes` directory, however, when I run `firebase deploy --only functions`, only my `onRequest.func.js` function is being deployed. I looked at the firebase functions:log and I got the following:

[image]

Even when I remove the check

```
if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME || process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === functionName)
```

my `onWrite.func.js` still is not deployed.

Am I doing something wrong? I would greatly appreciate any help!

> Edit: Here is my entire functions/ directory:
>   https://github.com/markoelez/temp_functions

Comment: It would be nice to have the github link to a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @x00 I linked my functions directory, hopefully that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in the code you've posted in the question. The issue is in the `*.func.js` files. This is the culprit:

```js
try {
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
} catch (err) {
    return err // looks like you should remove this line
}
```

When you `require` the second file `admin.initializeApp()` fails with

> Error: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initializeApp() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initializeApp() to give each app a unique name.

Then you exit the second module without assigning to `exports`.
If you remove `return err` you will have 2 exported functions in `index.js:exports`.

Don't know about the rest of the code, but that should resolve the issue in question.